# What is best way to communicate GPIO state from one linux machine to another

Tags: linux, nfs, gpio

I'm running a beaglebone and a raspberry pi.  I can read gpio easily on both in the path /sys/class/gpio.  I could use a web server easily to read a gpio state from one machine to the other, but I was wondering if there was a better lower level way to map the gpio folder over the network.  I tried NFS but I got this warning on the raspberry pi running debian wheezy image:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
[ ok ] Stopping NFS kernel daemon: mountd nfsd.
[ ok ] Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon....
[....] Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...exportfs: /etc/exports [1]:     Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export     "192.168.1.178:/sys/class/gpio".
  Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
  NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

exportfs: /sys/class/gpio does not support NFS export
. ok
[....] Starting NFS kernel daemon: nfsd
[warn] Not starting: portmapper is not running ... (warning).
```

So it doesn't look like gpio supports being mapped over NFS.  Does anyone know of another way to do it?

thanks!
Justin

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot map /proc or /dev over NFS either.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried with NFS but I was able to do it with sshfs. See my post [Set GPIO remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846574/set-gpio-remotely)