# Set GPIO remotely

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, nfs, sshfs

I haven't tried this yet but I don't think I can use NFS to set /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value remotely on a beaglebone. I think I read you could do this a different way but I would really like to write to a file on remote server and have it set /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value locally on beaglebone. I don't know how to link these two files up. I am using java to program but I don't think that should make a big difference.

[Using BeagleBone Black GPIOs](http://www.armhf.com/using-beaglebone-black-gpios/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if NFS will work this way to but I was able to set the value of /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value remotely using sshfs. Anyone interested in doing to same install sshfs on both host linux machine and beaglebone. From beaglebone `ssh -R 2000:localhost:22 root@<pc ipaddress maybe 192.168.7.1 or 192.168.7.3>`. From host linux machine after ssh into it from beaglebone `mkdir /mnt/remoteBB; sshfs -p2000 -o allow_other root@localhost:/ /mnt/remoteBB/`. You can then set the value file.

### Example workflow

On beaglebone:

`[root@alarm ~]# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value
1`

On host linux machine

`root@scw-27ca2d:~# cat /mnt/remoteBB/sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value
1
root@scw-27ca2d:~# echo 0 > /mnt/remoteBB/sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value
root@scw-27ca2d:~# cat /mnt/remoteBB/sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value
0`

On beaglebone:

`[root@alarm ~]# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/value
0`

Cheers!